# Why is "if(c != ' ' || c != '\n')" activating when it is not supposed to?

Tags: c, if-statement

My program counts the number of words, characters, and lines.

Example input:

> b
> b

Expected output:

> 4, 2, 2

Note that I enter `b` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then enter `b` again, after that, I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and the print statement occurs.

The problem is that I am getting:

> 4, 3, 2

I know the problem is because my if statement is activating, but when I run this program in my head, I don't understand why it should be activating at all.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int traversal = 1;
    unsigned long int charcount = 0;
    unsigned long int wordcount = 0;
    unsigned long  int linecount = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        charcount = charcount +1;

        if((c <= 'z' && c >= 'a') || (c <= 'Z' && c >= 'A') || c == '\'')
        {

            if (counter >= 1)
            {
                wordcount++;
                counter = 0;
                printf("counter\n");
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            if (c != ' ' || c != '\n')  //** This should only run if we get NO letter
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            linecount = linecount+1;
            wordcount = wordcount+1;
            traversal = traversal +1;
            printf("%lu\n", wordcount);
        }
        if(c == ' ')
        {
            wordcount = wordcount+1;
        }    
    }
    printf( "%lu %lu %lu\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount );
}
```

I am certain that the `if` statement I made only activates `c` at that time is not a newline (enter), or if it's a space. Why is it running? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at just your conditional:

```
if (c != ' ' || c != '\n')  //** This should only run if we get NO letter
```

Let's look at three cases:

1. If `c == ' '`, then we have `(false || true)` which is `true`
2. If `c == '\n'`, then we have `(true || false)` which is `true`
3. If `c == 'a'`, then we have `(true || true)` which is `true`.

You actually want:

```
if (c != ' ' && c != '\n')
```

Which means that we will execute the conditional statements when `c` is neither a space nor a newline character.